# How to call $this->emitSelf() multiple times on function

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have the following example function:

```
public function backupService()
{
   $job = Job::find($this->job_id);

   sleep(5);
 
   $job->status = 'in_progress';
   $job->update();
   $this->emitSelf('refreshComponent');

   sleep(10);
 
   $job->status = 'finished';
   $job->update();
   $this->emitSelf('refreshComponent');

}
```

When I change the status to 'in_progress' it changes in my database but doesn't update the component. Apparently it is only issuing $this->emitSelf() when the backupService() function finishes, ie the status will never appear as 'in_progress', only as 'finished'.

I don't want to use the wire:poll directive because I don't want to keep updating the page all the time, only when I specifically call it. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The event will be emitted once the entire method `backupService()` is finished with its execution, when the response from that method is sent back to the browser. Livewire-events are actually sent to the browser with the response, and any components listening for those events will be triggering actions on the client, making secondary-requests.

This means that the refresh-event that you emit, will trigger after everything is completed.

If you don't want to use polling, then another alternative is websockets. But this too can be a bit much for such a simple task, so a third alternative is to restructure your method into two methods, one that starts the process, and have events going from there. Something like this, where the first method is only responsible for setting the new status and emitting a new event that will be starting the job, and the second method is responsible for execution.

```php
protected $listeners = [
    'refreshComponent' => '$refresh',
    'runJob'
];

public function backupService()
{
    $job = Job::find($this->job_id);
    $job->status = 'in_progress';
    $job->update();

    $this->emitSelf('runJob', $job);
}

public function runJob(Job $job)
{
    sleep(10);
    $job->status = 'finished';
    $job->update();
    $this->emitSelf('refreshComponent');
}
```